# How to stop y-labels in matplotlib overlapping when plotting?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I was plotting a time/temperature series and the y-values kept overlapping as shown below:

[image]

The pandas dataframe looked like this:

| Time | Air | Prb1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:55:19.924 | 16.6 | 22.8 |
| 08:55:22.930 | 18.1 | 22.8 |
| 08:55:25.929 | 19.5 | 22.8 |

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was that Pandas had the air and probe 1 (Prb1) values as **objects** (checked using dataframe.info()). When they were changed to **float64** (by changing the string to float using float('string') before loading into Pandas) the plot displayed correctly as shown below:

[image]